# How to decode _0x*** strings in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, decode

Today, I found a javascript encoded start with _0x***
I wonder how to encode/decode javascript strings likes following url:
[JS Example (CodePad)](http://codepad.org/4k2BfPGI)

Is there anyone can tell me how to encode/decode like that? And maybe help to decode the javascript above as an example. Your help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: That's a variable name. There's nothing to decode.

Comment: This is the name of a variable, it's not encoded it was simply generated by an obfuscator.

Comment: Thanks for your answers!

Comment: Correction, this doesn't even look obfuscated. It's just a variable with a funny name.

Answer (score 0):

this [website](https://deobfuscate.io/) romoves some javascript  obfuscation but you still have to figure out what does the code do

Answer (score -1):

This is obfuscated JavaScript file and you can deobfuscating manual not tools for Deobfuscate this pattern.

This video on youtube can help you to manual deobfuscate javascript code:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ajB0OKA1yfQ

Comment: what about _0x**** ?

Comment: it's same no big deal